# Is a Champion a good tank?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I often run into trouble looking for groups in LOTRO, so often I use whatever I get. Often, a Champion is willing to join, but considering the way Champions burn down health in exchange for damage, I'm not sure if this is a good idea...

I know what the tanking classes are (Guardian and Warden) but I actually meant, would it work?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but would things improve if I had two healers? I often do.

Comment: In GA it should work out with a Champion as main tank and a second healer because there are no damage race encounters (so you won't miss a additional damage dealer that much). Personally i would choose a Captain as support healer/buffer and/or a Burgler or Lore-master as debuffer (prefering the Burglar because he can increase the threat generated by the Champion)

A good setup would be like: Champion (main tank), Bard (healer), Captain (support heal/buffer), Burglar (debuffer), two damage dealer (Hunter, Rune-keeper or Champion)

Comment: Bard? You mean Mini? I generally like RK's to heal.

Comment: Argh, sorry playing on a german client and yes i mean the Minstrel. A Rune-keeper is also ok as healer.

Comment: If you ask me, RK's make a way better healer than Minstrels (Rune of Restoration, for instance).

Comment: Well you can't say that. That highly depends on the instance, encounter, group and group size. The Minstrel is a direct healer while Rune-keeper is a HoT-healer. The Minstrel is a overall good group healer and the Rune-keeper is a excellent single target healer.

Comment: The answers here may no longer be relevant, as they were answered before the game overhauled the class system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Champion class is NOT a good main tank. If you compare a Champion with a Guardian or a Warden you'll find one or more deficits. The average Champion will have lesser block-, parry- and evade ratings, lesser critical hit protection, lesser damage reduction, lesser incoming heal, lesser skills for survivability and poor skills to get and gain aggro.

But a Champion can get used as main tank. But that highly depends on the skill, experience and equiptment of the Champion, the instance and the other members of the group. I did quite some main tanks runs with my Champion and i have also a Warden. If a rate the difficulty of instances/encounters with my Champion as main tank:

- Sammath Gûl: not easy but ok
- Halls of Crafting: quite difficult
- Great Barrows (Thadur/Sambrog): hard
- The Blind One in Dar Narbugud: very hard
- Durchest in Barad Guldur: is nearly impossible

and compare if the with the difficulty rating for my Warden:

- Sammath Gûl: easy
- Halls of Crafting: easy
- Great Barrows (Thadur/Sambrog): not easy but ok
- The Blind One in Dar Narbugud: difficulr
- Durchest in Barad Guldur: hard

It obvious that tanking with a tank class is just much easier.

Comment: I'm lvl 34 and do GA instances/quests.

Comment: For outdoor quest a Champion is suffient as main tanl. For the instances it can work out with a Champion as main tank but you have to get a good Champion player. Especially the first boss encounter in Garth Aragwen is very hard to tank as Champion.

Answer (score 5):

The Guardian class is the most effective tank in LOTR: Online. They don't typically burn through as much health in exchange for damage. A primary function of this class is crowd control which is necessary for tanking in a fellowship.

Champions are considered more of an off-tank and are generally thought to be the best soloing class if you plan on adventuring alone. They have some tank-like attributes but not as many as the Guardian class. Additionally, the Champion class does not have any adequate crowd control skills.

There is a lot more information about classes on the LOTR Wiki. Here are the links to both the Guardian and Champion wiki pages:

[Guardian Class Information](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Guardian)

[Champion Class Information](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Champion)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After the Helms Deep expansion (and complete redesign of the class system), Champions are now intended to be legitimate main tanks, if built that way.